# javascript with frames no value

Tags: javascript, popup, frames

I have an java application (legacy) which makes heavy use of frames and popups.  I need to close all the popups when I logoff the application.  I'm trying to access the popups using the frames object.  When I try to see how many frames there are I use the frames.length and the value is always 0.  What could be doing this?  The application is vary large and uses dhtmlx.

Comment: Can you post your javaSCRIPT code and an example of popup please?

Comment: function win(url,name,width,height) {
 leftPos = (screen.width-width)/2; 
 topPos = (screen.height-(height+110))/2;
 popup = window.open(url,name,'width='+ width +', height='+ height +', toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,copyhistoryno,left='+leftPos+',top='+topPos);
 
} // end Function

Comment: This is the function that is used to open the popup.  I am trying to get the 'popup' object that is created here.  I seem to get very lost in the frames.

Answer (score 2):

Popups are not frames. The only way to access them is through the return value of the call to `window.open`.

Comment: I know popups are not frames.  There is no return value from the window.open.  I think it may get lost due to the use of framesets to display the data.